# How to make a webapp, which takes url input and download the file

Tags: web-applications, download

how to make a webapp, which takes url input and
downloads the file to server and later can be seen in list.

Actually i'm trying to make a webapp, which downloads a file and convert it to some other extension, where  everyone can download it . Mainly in companies extensions with .zip or .exe
are blocked. so if this app changes somehow to .doc or etc., it will be helpful right?

Don't worry about file conversion and all, i will take care of tht, i just need how to make a webapp download a file and stores it in server.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible.  Do you have any languages / platforms in mind for what you'd like to host it on?

You wouldn't even need to download the file, but could instead proxy the connection.  A service could accept a URL parameter with the original request, then return a modified download - all without the original bytes ever touching the server's disk - which would be ideal in a situation like this.  You could do simple modifications, such as modifying the file extension, to something more elaborate, such as re-packaging the file into a TAR file or other non-blocked format.

That said, this is not the first option I would consider.  In fact, it would be near to the last.  There are probably better options here, many non-technical - such as understanding why certain extensions are blocked, and seeing if there is an exception policy for them that can be followed.  If these companies are already blocking certain file extensions, it's a pretty good bet that your service would quickly end up on the block list as well.

Comment: Its my private website, if websense blocks sites with category , and my site is not indexed in google also, i might have chance to work it out. this websense i donno , it acts like a child , some times when i download a zip file from box.com it downloads fine, sometimes it says blocked.
anyway,  i have knowledge in .net,jsp etc., 
and some shell scripting if any cron needed.

from what u said (instead proxy........then return a modified download ), how can i do that?
any refs and examples would be helpful

Comment: Is the site where you would host this outside of the web filtering?  If not, this won't be of any benefit to you.  If you still needed to proceed with this approach, I would do it as a Java servlet (one level lower than a JSP), but .Net would also certainly work as well.  Maybe someone else can add an answer with a better reference or example on how to do something like this - otherwise I may be available for hire.  :-)

Comment: Yes,my site is outside of web filtering. I'm just asking how to do it, irrelevant of technology(i can handle it) ,just need guidance and some reference/example. --- i could hire you, but this is my personal site,
i cannot invest money so much money on it.